# How does c# FileSystemWatcher handle multiple files?

Tags: c#, directory, filesystemwatcher, file-monitoring

If you have c# FileSystemWatcher monitoring a directory using the Created event how do you go about handling multiple files and processing them if the processing takes a certain period of time. So some files come in and then processing starts. If more files come in before the processing is finished how should this be handled or does the FileSystemWatcher Created event queue them?
Would you need to use async methods event handlers for this situation?

Comment: Are you OK with processing multiple files concurrently, or you would prefer to add them in a queue, and process them sequentially one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, FileSystemWatcher queue events, so no file events will be lost, however, if event registration is a time-dependent task, you should make an asynchronous event handler.